# Can't get value from ResultSet to populate jLabel in Java

Tags: java, jlabel, derby, resultset

I am new to programming and trying to assign a value from a sql query to a jLabel. The program compiles and runs with no errors but doesn't change the jLabel. According to my research, this should work, but doesn't. DB connection is fine. When I debug, the problem seems to be with the line: 
double d = rs.getDouble(1);
Here is my code:

```
String sum = "SELECT SUM(TOTAL) FROM PUNCHES WHERE EID = 1"; 

Statement st = con.createStatement();            
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sum); //rs should have 1 row, 1 column

double d = rs.getDouble(1);
lblGrandTotal.setText(String.valueOf(d));
```

If I substitute an arbitrary value like 12.345 for d, it works.

Comment: OK, you've got a problem in a complex program, one that combines GUI code and SQL database code. I strongly urge you not to do this, to instead divide the code into separately testable smaller units, and test the GUI separate from the database code. Get them both working before combining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `rs.next()`

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sum); //rs should have 1 row, 1 column
if (rs.next())
{
    double d = rs.getDouble(1);
    ...
}
else
    // Failed to get result, do something useful here
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. That solved the problem. Didn't realize I needed to iterate through a result set with only one result.

Comment: The virtual cursor is before the first row after the query.